# Creating a d3 v4 histogram with an ordinal scale

Tags: javascript, d3.js

This is my piece of code, I am unable to fetch the data in bins.
I am new to d3 and I think there is some problem with the ordinal or scaleband scale. Can anyone help.

```
    dom = (data.map(function(d) { return d[attri]; }));

    x = d3.scaleBand()      
   .range([0,width])
   .paddingInner([0.1])
   .paddingOuter([0.3])
   .align([0.5]);

   x.domain(dom);

   bins = d3.histogram()
  .domain(x.domain)
  (mydata);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two problems here.

First problem, `domain` as a getter (and as a setter as well) has parentheses:

```
x.domain()
```

But, unfortunately, that doesn't fix your code, you cannot do:

```
bins.domain(x.domain())
```

... for your histogram domain with the scale you have. The reason is the second problem:

In a d3 histogram, `domain` is an array with two values, the minimum and the maximum value. According to the documentation:

> If domain is specified, sets the domain accessor to the specified function or array and returns this histogram generator [...] The histogram domain is defined as an array [min, max], where min is the minimum observable value and max is the maximum observable value; both values are inclusive. Any value outside of this domain will be ignored when the histogram is generated. ([source](https://github.com/d3/d3-array/blob/master/README.md#histograms))

However, right now, your `x.domain()` is an array with several values (from `data.map`). You could do `x.domain()` to set your histogram domain **if** your scale were a linear one.

So, set your histogram domain properly.

Comment: I think we can have domains with  a set of values see this link below http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29318223/d3js-histogram-with-ordinal-scale. My domain is the same it contains values like ["marrried","unmarried","divorced"] etc. I want something similar to histogram.layout of v3 in v4

Comment: No, you can't. In that link, do you see the **histogram domain** as a set of values? Nope, because there is none. In that question the OP is using the ordinal scale simply to pass an array of values to histogram.

Comment: So is it not possible to plot what I want to achieve here? I am new to d3 can you help.

Comment: I'm simply saying to you that the `domain` in the histogram function is an array with two values. As this question has a specific problem that was already located, I suggest you post a **new** question, with an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and more specifications.

Comment: So how do I convert ["divorced","married", "NA/DF","never married","no histories","separated","widowed"] into just array of 2 values

Comment: Well, you can't. This is an histogram, not a bar chart. Histograms have **quantitative** variables to define the bins. It seems to me that you want a bar chart instead.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I will convert it to a bar chart :)

Comment: Yes, I believe that a bar chart suits you better. Have a look here to read about the differences between a bar chart and a histogram: http://stattrek.com/statistics/charts/histogram.aspx?Tutorial=AP, also here: https://www.edrawsoft.com/histogram-vs-bar-chart.php

Comment: Actually I am parsing a csv file and it has 7-8 attributes, all others are numbers so I have used a histogram but for this one I will have to convert it to a bar chart. Thanks for the link